# Onclick url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a url I want to rewrite because of bad programming from a noob develper.

The **php**

```
$branch = "lwh/main/"; // Dirs in URL from host to main folder
$pagebranch = "lwh/"; // URL branch for hyperlinks
$apages = "account/";
$bpages = "booking/";
$gpages = "general/";
$ppages = "product/";
```

**function**
// Global functions

```
function fetchdir($dir)     
{
   $protocol = $GLOBALS['protocol'];
    $host = $GLOBALS['host'];
    ($dir == $GLOBALS['apages'] || $dir == $GLOBALS['bpages'] || $dir == $GLOBALS['ppages'] || $dir == $GLOBALS['gpages'] ? $branch = $GLOBALS['pagebranch'] : $branch = $GLOBALS['branch']);
    echo $protocol.$host.$branch.$dir;
}

function fetchinline($dir)      
{   
    $protocol = $GLOBALS['protocol'];
    $host = $GLOBALS['host'];
    ($dir == $GLOBALS['apages'] || $dir == $GLOBALS['bpages'] || $dir == $GLOBALS['ppages'] || $dir == $GLOBALS['gpages'] ? $branch = $GLOBALS['pagebranch'] : $branch = $GLOBALS['branch']);
    return $protocol.$host.$branch.$dir;
}
```

so lets says I had index.php, about.php in the `general folder`

```
<a href="<?php fetchdir($gpages); ?>index.php">Home</a>
<a href="<?php fetchdir($gpages); ?>contact.php">Home</a>
```

but the problem is in the url it will be

```
http://www.urltest.x10.mx/lwh/general/index.php
http://www.urltest.x10.mx/lwh/booking/car.php
```

**MY question**
How can I rewrite the url so that when you click on any of the links in `general folder` it will be like 
  http://www.urltest.x10.mx/index.php

and in `booking folder` it will be like this http://www.urltest.x10.mx/booking/car.php

I want to rewrite the url when you click on any of the links.

**I have tried**
**In my root directory**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^lwh/
RewriteRule (.*) /lwh/main/pages/general/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^lwh/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ lwh/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^urltest.x10.mx [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.urltest.x10.mx/$1 [R=301,L]



AuthName "root"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
Options -Indexes
```

In the **lwh** folder I have

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^general/(.*)$ lwh/main/pages/general/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^account/(.*)$ lwh/main/pages/account/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^booking/(.*)$ lwh/main/pages/booking/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ lwh/main/pages/product/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^$ lwh/main/pages/account/ [L]
RewriteRule ^$ lwh/main/pages/general/ [L]
RewriteRule ^$ lwh/main/pages/booking/ [L]
RewriteRule ^$ lwh/main/pages/product/ [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /lwh/main/pages/general/index.php
Options -Indexes
AuthName "main"
```

to hide the `lwh` folder but when i click on a link i still get the fill url...

Please can someone help

Comment: if anyone want to see the actaul url link. Please let me know

Comment: Why don't you put the rewite rules in the root `.htaccess` file like `RewriteRule ^booking/(.*)$ lwh/main/pages/booking/$1 [L]`

Comment: @dianuj if i do that it wouldn't work. I have tried it

Comment: anyone know how to do this please